# Do I need to start a new game for each scenario?

Tags: fate-of-the-world

I finished up the first scenario, "The Rise of Africa," and at the end, the tutorial tooltip says I can either keep looking at stats or exit to the menu.

I assumed that my saves for each scenario would all be in one save, however, that doesn't seem to be the case. When I load up the save that I made during the Africa scenario, it just puts me back at the end of it again.

Do I start a fresh game for every scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Longer answer: Different scenarios not only have different objectives and failure conditions, but also change things like the starting state of the Earth (e.g. Cornucopia where the Earth starts with an abundance of fossil fuels, or Earth Day where all regions start with a Green outlook). Because of these changes, you'll likely need to employ different strategies to meet your victory conditions or just stay out of trouble.